# Reverse image search for specific website

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, .net, json

Is it possible to take a picture and search for similar images for a specific website? I have an e-commerce website and looking for this features in where the user can take a picture from their devices and return similar matches on a page. I am fine with any API services.

Comment: You can use Google's custom search API - https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get an image search on your page is using google custom search api: https://cse.google.com/cse/

I assume this will fullfil your requirements.

If you want to dig deeper you could use image recognition APIs from differnt cloud providers.

There are several solutions for Image recognition around:

Google Cloud Vision -> https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Amazon Rekognition -> https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/getting-started

Clarifai -> https://clarifai.com/

Watson Visual Recognition -> https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/visual-recognition/

You may also want to try more complex solution and using directly OpenCV -> https://opencv.org/

Here some getting started instructions, when you are using C#: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/a-quick-introduction-to-computer-vision-using-c-sharp/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes...I think something like **Clarifai** could be helpful http://clarifai.com

API Guide: https://clarifai.com/developer/guide/